# Removing trailing slash and redirecting html

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, slash, trailing

The problem I'm having is that the first URL works and the second one doesn't.

http://www.example.com/podcast/episode1
http://www.example.com/podcast/episode1/

Is there a way to redirect all trailing slash versions to the non-trailing slash version?

The problem is even worse here, since neither of these work:

example.com/podcast
example.com/podcast/

Only this one works:

example.com/podcast.html

and I do not want the html extension visible.

Here's the code I have in my .htaccess file so far:

```
#shtml

AddType text/html .html
AddHandler server-parsed .html

#html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#index redirect

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]

#non www to www

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Also looking to have the html version redirect to the non-html version. For example, I want http://www.pavlinaplus.com/podcast/reality.html to redirect to http://www.pavlinaplus.com/podcast/reality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the trailing slash is easy. Removing the `.html` isn't.

## Removing the slash

Just R=301 redirect if you see a slash on there.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]`

Don't add the `L` flag since you want to continue processing this request. Also make it the first rule.

## Why you can't remove the `.html`

Your issue is that once `page` becomes `page.html` (via the internal redirect), a **new** request for `page.html` is given to the server. So then your .htaccess will see the request for `page.html` and redirect to `page`. Cue infinite loop.

## Optimising your code

1. You only need `RewriteEngine On` once at the top of your `.htaccess`
2. You should add the `www` redirect to the top of your code and remove the `L` flag (see *Removing the Slash*)

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for your help. The code partially works and partially doesn't. Visit [the trailing slash version](http://www.pavlinaplus.com/newsletter/checklist/) to see what happens (the [non trailing slash version](http://www.pavlinaplus.com/newsletter/checklist) still works). Any idea what could be causing it to take the long route?

Comment: How do I get rid of the _home/theev8/public_html/_ part of the URL?

Comment: This is an issue with your `RewriteBase`. You can set it to `/` which should fix the issue - under the `RewriteEngine On`, add `RewriteBase /`. This changes the rewriting-path - [Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Now it's telling me I have too many redirects. Hmm. [http://www.pavlinaplus.com/podcast/](http://www.pavlinaplus.com/podcast/)

Comment: Here's a mirror image of my .htaccess file [{link}](http://www.pavlinaplus.com/htaccess.html)

Comment: I have ascertained that the `RewriteRule` pertaining to `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is causing the issue. The loop doesn't occur for a 404 error. I'm looking into this. Edit: Hmm... http://www.pavlinaplus.com/htaccess does not cause this issue. Only `/podcasts` and `/newsletter` cause this issue. Are they folders, and is there `/podcasts.html` and `/newsletter.html`?

Comment: They are folders and they are html files as well, so I can guess that that might be an issue (podcast.html exists atm, newsletter.html hasn't been created yet)

Comment: And I really don't want to make the folder names different; the idea is that people can delete part of the URL and "back up" to another page, so to speak.

Comment: I think the issue is to do with them being directories, my guess is that removing the `/` causes it to re-add it (since it's a directory) and it promptly removes it again, and so on. I don't really have a lot of time to myself at the moment, but I was unable to reproduce this on my local machine (it is worth noting, however, that it kept putting the slash back on before redirecting to the `.html` page). Your best options are probably either to put an `index.html` in the folder and access `/foldername.html` that way, or add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` on the slash-removing rule.

Comment: I don't have a lot of directories, there's only a few pages like the "podcast" page. Is there a way to to manually redirect http://www.pavlinaplus.com/podcast/ to .../podcast.html and then I use the same type of code for the other couple of pages?

Comment: I have tried your directory index.html method and it works extremely well, so I'll stick with that. So now I can access my page by going to: /podcast/. Is it correct to say that probably no browser will display the real file name (index.html)?

Comment: It's the server that looks for the index.html, so the browser will never show it. It does however, fall under the same category as the other html pages - you can't redirect them away if they go directly to index.html in the browser (although I don't know how Apache looks for the index.html, you might be able to redirect away).

Comment: For some reason this URL doesn't work when I type it in with the trailing slash. [http://www.pavlinaplus.com/newsletter/checklist/](http://www.pavlinaplus.com/newsletter/checklist/) All other URLs redirect fine with trailing slashes though.

Comment: It's removing it for me. Could be a caching problem?

Comment: Dear Scott, Can you solve my problem with trailing slash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608615/trailing-slash-remove-in-www-mysite-com-i-bc