# Trailing slash remove in www.mysite.com/#i-bc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, redirect

I want to go to a particular div on my home page itself when select on change event. I want result like `www.mysite.com#i-bc` but trailing slash added in between them like `www.mysite.com/#i-bc`. I want to remove that trailing slash using jquery or something else. here is my code:

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-view').on('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url) {
            window.location.hash = url;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

My html is like this:

```
<select class="toggle-view">
    <option value="#i-bc">1</option>
    <option value="#i-st">2</option>
    <option value="#i-mm">3</option>
    <option value="#i-cc">4</option>
</select>

<div id="i-bc">some content here </div>
<div id="i-st">some content here </div>
<div id="i-mm">some content here </div>
<div id="i-cc">some content here </div>
```

Thanks InAdvance

Comment: Hi Immran, I saw [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/70576165) - why do you need to remove the `/` after the domain? [This question/answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/73986/47104) and [this other question/answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/33074/47104) describe that both with and without the `/`, the URL _is equivalent_. [RFC2616 §3.2.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2) and [RFC3986 §6.2.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-6.2.3) suggest a trailing `/` is preferred. You may have a valid reason - if so, please let me know.

Comment: Glad to see your comment here,  I want to go to an another div in the same page (that is my home page which contains `/` at the end) when onchange trigger apply. I want something like this `mysite.com#i-bc` or `mysite.com#i-bc/` but not `mysite.com/#i-bc`.

Comment: The `/` indicates the _path_, and **must** occur before the `#` (which indicates the _fragment_), if both are present. You need to use `example.com/my/url#abc` and not `example.com#abc/my/url` (this would set the _fragment_ [`#`] to `abc/my/url`). The [specification _demands_ this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3); you cannot change the order. 

Note: I asked **why** you need this - your code should still work with the `/`. You might also want to consider the [HTML5 History API](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/) - this removes the need for `#` (_fragments_).

Answer (score 0):

Better use `window.location.hash`. Its better than `href`

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('.toggle-view').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val();
          if (url) {
              window.location.hash = url;
                    }
          return false;
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Not working, moreover adding all option values every time on change

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-view').on('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url) {
           window.location.hash = url;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

`window.location.hash` is specifically used to play with hashed urls.

Comment: Yes, but how to remove `/` in result webpage url. i am looking for something like replace this `/` with ` ` before append the in page uri

Comment: / wont come in this case,

Comment: still exist. i have no clue why this happen. is there any way to remove manually by using script.? That will be helpfull for me.

Comment: window.location = window.location.replace(/\/$/, '') + url; replace this line and check

Comment: I think, this means there is nothing to replace in this url. May be `/` added by default from database

Comment: window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('/')) + url; Try this, and don't give up that early.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132982/discussion-between-v-for-vendetta-and-immran-mohammed).